# How can I use parted to delete lvm and create new extended?

Tags: centos, partition, lvm, kvm, parted

I have a CentoS 6 KVM VM installed on Proxmox with the following disk configuration.

Could anyone guide me on how to remove the current /dev/sda2 using parted and then add it back extending the disk space from 10GB to 25GB.

`parted /dev/sda print` output

```
[root@ip52 ~]# parted /dev/sda print
Model: QEMU QEMU HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 53.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   primary  ext4         boot
 2      525MB   10.7GB  10.2GB  primary               lvm
```

`fdisk -l` output

```
[root@ip126 ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 26.8 GB, 26843545600 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 25600 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 2048 * 512 = 1048576 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00086c7a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           2         501      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2             502       10240     9972736   8e  Linux LVM
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.

Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root: 9168 MB, 9168748544 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1114 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap: 1040 MB, 1040187392 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 126 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

`pvdisplay` output

```
[root@ip126 ~]# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               VolGroup
  PV Size               9.51 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2434
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          2434
  PV UUID               2lmvRB-u3AL-DYAX-2Azh-HsHE-skwW-3hewTE
```

`vgdisplay` output

```
[root@ip126 ~]# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               VolGroup
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               9.51 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2434
  Alloc PE / Size       2434 / 9.51 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               tp0a2o-Hkup-3V0m-01K1-udfY-Y2l2-gTMHjg
```

`lvdisplay` output

```
[root@ip126 ~]# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/VolGroup/lv_root
  LV Name                lv_root
  VG Name                VolGroup
  LV UUID                9xV22O-69gz-fib7-t3tF-ksqc-LWhj-KLYful
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2018-05-23 09:31:01 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                8.54 GiB
  Current LE             2186
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/VolGroup/lv_swap
  LV Name                lv_swap
  VG Name                VolGroup
  LV UUID                0iRAF9-rF8Y-kpn2-rPyV-fnAW-Q2vq-aK2ODT
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2018-05-23 09:31:02 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                992.00 MiB
  Current LE             248
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
```

Comment: Why not just expand the partition and then expand the structures?

Comment: If you want to replace that partition with a larger one that's fine. But if you insist on using `parted` please provide the disk structure from `parted /dev/sda print` instead of `fdisk`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for me is to

1. add new partition `/dev/sda3` (for example). You can use fdisk for
   this purpose.
2. Create on this partition PV `pvcreate /dev/sda3`
3. Add this PV to the VG `vgextend VolGroup /dev/sda3`
4. Add new LV: `lvcreate -L 5G VolGroup  VolGroup _newvolume` This will
   create new volume, named VolGroup _newvolume, 5GB size
5. Extend existing volume: `lvextend -L +5G /dev/VolGroup/lv_root;
   resize2fs /dev/VolGroup/lv_root` This command will extend lv_root by
   5GB

and then extend LV's or create new LV's

Comment: How do I add a new partition in parted?

Comment: as the superuser, run `parted` and inside `parted` you will use the `mkpart` command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can't seem to get it working what am I doing wrong? https://pastebin.com/exAU5a1s

Comment: @masterq, you add the PV to the VG. But you did not extend the LV's or not create new one.See my edited answer